# Flutter : Android license status unknown

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter

I have seen similar issues but they somehow could not resolve my issue.
I am currently using Windows and Versions Java 8, Java SDK 13.0.1, Android Studio v3.5.2.

1) I First typed `flutter doctor` and got the following error : Android license status unknown.

2) I then entered `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and got the following command

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

3) Running this line I ended up here :

```
D:\flutter\flutter>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

Please let me know the simple steps i could follow as I am confused about this a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, try running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. This should prompt you to accept licenses just type y and enter to accept the licence if error persists check out [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16025)

Comment: he said he did that